What would the flow rate be?
What would the flow rate be?
The tubing is 1 m of 1/8 inch diameter stainless steel. Initially the system is pressurised to 3 bar and sealed. There is a leak, making the pressure in the system drop to 1 bar after 20 minutes. What is the flow rate of this leak?

Is this homework?

No - trying to set up a rig for experimental work and want o ensure we have the correct parts ordered for what this flow rate would be.

any help would be appreciated! I'm new to this research area

I may not be able to help (I'm an EE but it's a bit like an R-C capacitor exponential discharge curve) but I think you could clarify: it sounds like one end of the tube is at constant 3 bar and the other at constant 1 bar. Is that correct? Where does the 1 atm come into the picture? Also, where does the 20 minutes come into it? You're looking for a rate not a total volume which would be rate x time. [Edit] all the information into the question - not buried here in the comments. Welcome to E.SE.

What material is the tubing?

The tubing is 1/8 inch diameter stainless steel. Initially the system is pressurised to 3 bar and sealed. There is a leak, making the pressure in the system drop to 1 bar after 20 minutes.

So how much gas gets lost when the pressure difference is 2 bar and you know the volume?

It's still not perfectly clear. Are the 3 bar and 1 bar gauge readings relative to atmospheric pressure (4 bar and 2 bar absolute)? (I ask because if 1 bar is atmospheric then there is an ever decreasing ΔP and the discharge theoretically never ends.) And Mike is right; we need to know the container volume.

Are the 3 bar and 1 bar gauge readings relative to atmospheric pressure (4 bar and 2 bar absolute)? - Yes, these are gauge readings

Volume = 7.8919892552427E-6 meters3

So what about PV = nRT for both states?

As requested, Sarah, all the information should be in your question - not scattered through the comments.

I would not bore you with the calculations since it is already given above.
The flow rate of the leak is approximately
3.20×10 power −5
3.20×10 power −5
moles per minute. This represents the amount of gas escaping from the system per minute over the 20-minute period.

If the flow is laminar, the flowrate could be proportional to the pressure difference using a unknown coefficient $k$. In this case, the discharge should be exponential.
$$\dot{m}(t) = k\cdot \Delta P = k\cdot \left(P(t)-P_{atm}\right)$$
I assume there is some initial mass of pressurised gas $m_0$ at $t=0$. This can be calculated from given container volume $V$ and density $\rho$, which will vary with pressure (assuming ideal gas at a constant temperature $T$):
$$m_0 = V\cdot \rho(P) = \frac{V\cdot M}{R\cdot T}\cdot P(t)$$
Now the change in mass at a time can be expressed as:
$$\dot{m}(t) = \frac{dm(t)}{dt} = -V\cdot d\rho(P) = -\frac{V\cdot M}{R\cdot T}\cdot \frac{dP(t)}{dt}$$
Substituting this back to the 1st equation:
$$-\frac{V\cdot M}{R\cdot T}\cdot \frac{dP(t)}{dt} = k\cdot \left(P(t)-P_{atm}\right)$$
With $K = \frac{k\cdot R\cdot T}{V\cdot M}$:
$$\frac{dP(t)}{dt} = K\cdot \left(P_{atm}-P(t)\right)$$
Separating variables and integrating:
$$\int\limits_{P_0}^{P(t)}\frac{1}{P_{atm}-P(t)}dP(t) = K\cdot\int\limits_0^t dt = K\cdot t$$
$$\ln\left(\frac{P_{atm}-P(t)}{P_{atm}-P_0}\right) = -K\cdot t$$
$$\frac{P_{atm}-P(t)}{P_{atm}-P_0} = \exp(-K\cdot t)$$
Final expression for the container pressure $P$ as a function of time $t$:
$$P(t) = P_{atm} + \left(P_0-P_{atm}\right)\cdot \exp(-K\cdot t)$$
You know initial pressure $P_0$. You also know that in infinite time the pressure in the container should approach the atmospheric pressure $P_{atm}$. Both of these are already factored in the equation. The last one is specific known pressure $P_2$ after some time $t_2$:
$$P_2 = P(t=t_2) = P_{atm} + \left(P_0-P_{atm}\right)\cdot \exp(-K\cdot t_2)$$
From this:
$$K = -\frac{1}{t_2}\cdot \ln\left(\frac{P_{atm}-P_2}{P_{atm}-P_0}\right)$$
So the unknown leak rate constant $k$ could be calculated from:
$$k = \frac{V\cdot M}{t_2\cdot R\cdot T}\cdot \ln\left(\frac{P_{atm}-P_0}{P_{atm}-P_2}\right)$$
In your case, $K \dot{=} 0.00092294$, so the pressure in time may look like this:

Finally, you can calculate the flowrate from:
$$\dot{m}(t) = k\cdot \left(P_0-P_{atm}\right)\cdot \exp(-K\cdot t)$$
The initial assumption of flowrate proportionality to pressure difference might not be valid. More general approach would be to use minor loss formula:
$$\Delta P = \frac{1}{2}\cdot k_2\cdot \rho\cdot v^2$$
where:

$k_2$ is unknown coefficient (different to $k$)
$\rho$ is fluid density
$v$ is fluid speed

